# Missing code from class diagrams, auto-repair fails?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, class-diagram

Okay, this is driving me nuts: I have a Visual Studio project with couple of class diagrams which apparently are "broken". When I open them, I get this prompt:

[image: VS2010 prompt]

I click "Yes", and Visual Studio does its thing - it takes a moment, maybe 10-20 seconds. Problem is this happens every single time I close and open the diagram!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Class diagrams are XML iirc. open the XML and see if there is something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you delete that class diagram and create a new one...

Comment: Create a new class diagram and copy paste entire classes. Save after each class and reopen every. You might find out which class is corrupt and the corruption can even go away.

Comment: Thanks. And I guess we'll never know exactly *what* was the problem. :)

Comment: @Jakob: Sometimes it's just not worth the effort... :-)